# How to control db2 export lobfile name?

Tags: sql, join, db2, export, blob

I have a query as follow and will return me multiple result:

```
select bac.approvingContent, bac.content, b.code from smeadm.billerAttachmentContent bac inner join smeadm.billerAttachment ba on bac.contentId = ba.attachmentId
inner join smeadm.biller b on ba.billerId = b.billerId
where b.code in ('100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','112','113','114','115');
```

The `approvingContent` and `content` are store in `BLOB` format.

I export it to lobs file by follow query:

```
EXPORT TO MyFile.DEL OF DEL LOBS TO . LOBFILE lob 
MODIFIED BY lobsinsepfiles
select bac.approvingContent, bac.content, b.code from smeadm.billerAttachmentContent bac inner join smeadm.billerAttachment ba on bac.contentId = ba.attachmentId
inner join smeadm.biller b on ba.billerId = b.billerId
where b.code in ('100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','112','113','114','115');
```

I will get many lobfiles like `lob.001.lob`, `lob.002.lob`, `lob.001.lob` and so on.

I wish to export those lobfiles to more meaning filename, for example it will follow the b.code, like `100.lob`, `101.lob` and so on. Else I not sure which blob file is belong to which b.code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EXPORT command in Db2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) has only the LOB-related options you are already using. Based on the data generated by Db2 you can see the connection between your `b.code` and the lob files:

In the generated CSV file there should be three columns per row. The third column should be your `b.code`. The first and second column should have the file name for the BLOB for `approvingContent` and `content`.